# Scrolling pdf file which is opened in child window by using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

I came across one scenario where i need to scroll up and down pdf file which is opened in the child window.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll over height of window or browser.

Declare `JavascriptExecutor` first

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

**Scroll down page till bottom:**

```
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

**Scroll up page**

```
js.executeScript(“window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight,0)”);
```